# Recover data on a m.2 SSD from an usb adaptor and ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ssd, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to recover data from a m.2 ssd (Western Digital PC SN520 NVMe SSD M.2 2280-S3-B-M) but can't make it right now.

Can you please help me out ?

I'm using an USB adaptor ([This guy](https://www.cdiscount.com/informatique/boitiers-pc-alimentations/inateck-boitier-ssd-m-2-nvme-transmission-de-10gb/f-10766-ina6972085132980.html)).
But nothing shows in removable devices when I plug it in so I started trying to reach it within bash.

When typing `ls /dev/ | grep sd`,
I get : `sda`

which doesn't show when it's unplugged so I guess it's connecting correctly. Plus the blue led on the adaptor lights up when plugged.

I tried `sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt`
which answers `mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/sda.`

I tried `sudo smartctl /dev/sda` which answers :

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-48-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

NVMe device successfully opened

Use 'smartctl -a' (or '-x') to print SMART (and more) information
```

Then
`sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`
answers

```
Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode
```

When trying `sudo parted -l` I dont get anything located at /dev/sda, only my internal drives...

Similarly, `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` answers

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: No such file or directory
```

And `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda` answers :

```
/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
        Likely used: 1
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       0       0
        heads           0       0
        sectors/track   0       0
        --
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        IORDY not likely
        Cannot perform double-word IO
        R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
        DMA: not supported
        PIO: pio0
```

This is all I could try and I think that my best bet is to look up into the smartctl answer which says "scsi error unsupported scsi opcode" but I really can't find anything about it except that my adaptor is supposed to handle B+M SSDs..

Do you guys have any idea of what's going on please ? And how could I reach some data in that dang thing ?

Thanks in advance

Quentin

EDIT
Thanks guys I appreciate your help but I can't reinsert the ssd just yet.. will try to find a way then.

For now, I have tried `ddrescue` on the SSD through USB and got it working but nothing was copied I believe.

Log file says

```
# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.26
# Command line: ddrescue -f -n /dev/sda ./ima.img ./recovery.log
# Start time:   2022-09-27 22:58:22
# Current time: 2022-09-27 22:58:22
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status  current_pass
0x00000000     +               1
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x00000000  ?
```

Comment: Alternative: Reinsert the M.2 thingie in the computer *(assuming it works better there)*, find an external drive bay for a disk to save data on, copy the data from the M.2 into a temporary location (to not stress the failing disk), the mount the image as a loop device and run "Testdisk" on it, from e.g. Ubuntu install media in "Try Ubuntu" mode. *It has to turn up in `lsblk` or `fdisk -l` output.*

Comment: I expect your data is gone and may require a specialist (think someone who can desolder chips and read them) to get the data back.

Comment: If its an option, I agree with @hannu - You can use ddrescue to try clone the whole disk, and that should be the first step. If you can do it through USB, great. If not putting it in a computer reduces the number of abstraction layers.